# Mongodb ldap authentication through Java driver

Tags: mongodb, authentication, ldap, mongodb-java

Does anyone have an example of how to authenticate to a mongodb 2.5 server (soon to be 2.6) with LDAP authentication using the Java driver?

Answer (score 3):

You can find an example in the Java driver source [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/2.12.x/src/examples/example/PlainCredentialsExample.java).  Typically, you would use "$external" as the value of the source parameter to the com.mongodb.MongoCredential#createPlainCredential method, as in the [shell example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#authenticate-in-the-mongo-shell) in the 2.6 Release Notes.

Note also that since the password is sent as plain test over a network, you should plan to configure your driver and MongoDB cluster to use [SSL connections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/).